# What is the action of fermionic Hamiltonian $\mu_1 n_1 + \mu_2 n_2 + U n_1 n_2$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, path-integral, grassmann-numbers

## Problem

Consider a Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
H(c^\dagger, c) = \mu_1 c_1^\dagger c_1 + \mu_2 c_2^\dagger c_2 + U c_1^\dagger c_1 c_2^\dagger c_2\,,
\end{equation}
where $c_i$ are fermionic operators. Following e.g. [Altland, Simons. Condensed Matter Field Theory](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/condensed-matter-field-theory/0A8DE6503ED868D96985D9E7847C63FF), the partition function, written as a functional path integral, is
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Tr}e^{-\beta H} = 
\int D (\psi,\bar\psi) \exp\left\{
-\int_0^\beta d \tau \bar\psi(\tau)\cdot\partial_\tau\psi(\tau) + H(\bar\psi(\tau),\psi(\tau))
\right\}\,,
\end{equation}
which for our Hamiltonian yields
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{res}
\int D (\psi,\bar\psi) \exp\left\{
-\int_0^\beta d \tau \bar\psi\cdot\partial_\tau\psi + 
\mu_1 \bar\psi_1\psi_1 + \mu_2 \bar\psi_2\psi_2 + U \bar\psi_1\psi_1 \bar\psi_2\psi_2
\right\} = 1 + e^{-\beta\mu_1} + e^{-\beta\mu_2} + e^{-\beta(\mu_1 + \mu_2 + U)}
\end{equation}
However, using this result I arrive at a discrepancy: Let's make variable change $\psi_1 \mapsto \bar\psi_1$, $\bar\psi_1 \mapsto \psi_1$. This should not change the partition function (with a possible exception of an overall minus sign). The kinetic term transform as $\bar\psi_1\partial_\tau\psi_1 \mapsto \psi_1\partial_\tau\bar\psi_1 = \partial_\tau(\psi_1\bar\psi_1) + \bar\psi_1\partial_\tau\psi_1$, and so we get
\begin{equation}
Z = \int D (\psi,\bar\psi) \exp\left\{
- (\psi_1\bar\psi_1)|_0^\beta -\int_0^\beta d \tau 
\bar\psi_1\partial_\tau\psi_1 +
\bar\psi_2\partial_\tau\psi_2
-\mu_1 \bar\psi_1\psi_1 + \mu_2 \bar\psi_2\psi_2 - U \bar\psi_1\psi_1 \bar\psi_2\psi_2
\right\} 
\end{equation}
Due to the anti-periodic boundary conditions $\psi_1(\beta) = - \psi_1(\beta)$, $\bar\psi_1(\beta) = -\bar\psi_1(\beta)$, the boundary term vanishes, and by Eq. \eqref{res}, we get
\begin{equation}
Z = 1 + e^{\beta\mu_1} + e^{-\beta\mu_2} + e^{-\beta(-\mu_1 + \mu_2 - U)}\,,
\end{equation}
which is a wrong result (the discrepancy is obvious if we set $\mu_1=\mu_2=0$, in which case we get $Z = 3 + e^{\beta U}$ vs. the correct result of $Z = 3 + e^{-\beta U}$).

## Possible solution

My presumption is that the correct expression for the partition function should be
\begin{equation} \tag{2}\label{sol}
\operatorname{Tr}e^{-\beta H} = \int D (\psi,\bar\psi) \exp\left\{
-\int_0^\beta d \tau \bar\psi\cdot\partial_\tau\psi + 
\mu_1 \bar\psi_1\psi_1 + \mu_2 \bar\psi_2\psi_2 + U \left(\bar\psi_1\psi_1 + \frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\bar\psi_2\psi_2 + \frac{1}{2}\right)
\right\}\,,
\end{equation}
which under the problematic substitution $\psi_1 \mapsto \bar\psi_1$, $\bar\psi_1 \mapsto \psi_1$ becomes
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Tr}e^{-\beta H} = \int D (\psi,\bar\psi) \exp\left\{
-\int_0^\beta d \tau \bar\psi\cdot\partial_\tau\psi 
-\mu_1 \bar\psi_1\psi_1 + (\mu_2+U) \bar\psi_2\psi_2 
- U \left(\bar\psi_1\psi_1 + \frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\bar\psi_2\psi_2 + \frac{1}{2}\right)
\right\} \\
= 1 + e^{\beta\mu_1} + e^{-\beta(\mu_2+U)} + e^{-\beta(-\mu_1 + \mu_2)}
= e^{\beta\mu_1}(e^{-\beta\mu_1} + 1 + e^{-\beta(\mu_1+\mu_2+U)} + e^{-\beta \mu_2})\,,
\end{equation}
which is the correct result (up to a multiplicative constant), however I don't know how to justify expression \eqref{sol}, not to mention that it is not consistent with the literature known to me.